# Miles per hex on Fantasy World Generator maps

Tags: dnd-5e, maps, hexagonal-mapping

I have started using http://5e.d20srd.org/fantasy/world/ to try to make a good D&D world. Problem is it doesn't say how many miles per hex is.
Does anyone know the answer?? If you use Earth as a model, each hex would be 250 miles but that doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 8):

There are some guidelines in the DMG for mapping your world, starting at page 14.

They suggest that for the widest scale (which they call "Mapping a Continent") that you should use about 60 miles per hex. This will make a world a bit smaller than Earth, but still something plenty big for a campaign.

They've also got some other useful guidelines for mapping out terrain, kingdoms and civilizations that might help you.

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard overland hex size used throughout the ecosystem of published materials.  It changes from publisher to publisher, author to author, and sometimes even from one version of D&D to the next.  For smaller-scale areas used in hexcrawl play, 5-mile, 6-mile, and 10-mile hexes seem to be common, although I've also seen 24-mile and 30-mile hexes used by authors who like each hex to represent a full day's travel.

For a full-world map, such as those generated by the site you linked, a larger hex size is obviously called for, so that you don't need hundreds of thousands of hexes.  I haven't counted the dimensions of the maps generated by that site, but the 250-mile hexes you came up with for an Earth-sized world sound about right to me.

Comment: an encounter map could use hexes also at 5 ft. this was common in early D&D.

Comment: May want to change 'no standard' to 'no actual standard found among the diverse landscape of published materials' or something; as Erik points out, there are some standards given in the DMG, though I think you are correct that 3rd party production does not really follow them at all.

Comment: 3.5e defaulted to 24 mi hexes. Iirc, 5e prefers 60 mi (continent), 10 mi (realm), and 1 mi (provincial).